# Can't run Typeorm migrations in nestjs

Tags: postgresql, migration, nestjs, typeorm

I was following this blog https://wanago.io/2022/07/25/api-nestjs-database-migrations-typeorm/ to setup migrations in my nestjs project but got the error that dataSourceFileExport i.e DataSource object exported from the migration.config.ts is not iterable. And I don't know why it's not iterable. I couldn't find the solution on any platform

[Error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WkR9.png)

[migration.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pkkZ.png)

[migration scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQcsu.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9327) introduced in TypeORM v0.3.8 and fixed in v0.3.9

Answer (score 0):

Change in `migration.config.ts`:

```
export const AppDataSource: Datasource = new DataSource({...})
```